# Does utf8_unicode_ci collation support Thai and Indonesian?

Tags: mysql, unicode, utf-8

I'm creating a multilingual WordPress network/multisite. Each site in the network is dedicated for one country. There will be one site in Thai and another in Indonesian.

Comment: That is a *collation*, not a *character set*. Whether MySQL can handle those languages depends on the MySQL version you're using and the language specifics which I don't know. Before MySQL 5.5, it could only store up to three bytes per character, now it can store four bytes per character if necessary. See [MySQL documentation on Unicode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html) .

Comment: I really can't see how this is not a real question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-sets.html):

> MySQL implements the xxx_unicode_ci collations according to the
>   Unicode Collation Algorithm (UCA) described at
>   http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/. The collation uses the
>   version-4.0.0 UCA weight keys:
>   http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCA/4.0.0/allkeys-4.0.0.txt ... 
>   Some characters are not supported yet.

The collations you're asking for should be covered in there (I've found Thai and Bahasa characters), but you better give it a try with some sample text before going live.